# Django showing error 'constraints' refers to the joined field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-validation

I have two models Product and Cart. Product model has  `maximum_order_quantity`. While updating quantity in cart, I'll have to check whether quantity is greater than `maximum_order_quantity`at database level. For that am comparing quantity with `maximum_order_quantity` in Cart Model But it throws an error when I try to migrate

`cart.CartItems: (models.E041) 'constraints' refers to the joined field 'product__maximum_order_quantity'`.

Below are my models

```
class Products(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products"
    )
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    base_price = models.IntegerField()
    product_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="photos/products", null=True, blank=True
    )
    stock = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    maximum_order_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
)
```

```
class CartItems(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cart Items"
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
            check=models.Q(quantity__gt=models.F("product__maximum_order_quantity")),
            name="Quantity cannot be more than maximum order quantity"
            )
        ]
```

## Error

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
cart.CartItems: (models.E041) 'constraints' refers to the joined field 'product__maximum_order_quantity'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference fields on related models in database-level constraints like `CheckConstraint`.

The error message you received is indicating that you cannot reference the `maximum_order_quantity` field of the `Products` model in the constraints attribute of the `CartItems` model.

The reason for this is that the `maximum_order_quantity` field is a property of the `Products` model, and in the `CartItems` model, you are referencing it through a foreign key relationship. Specifically, you are using the syntax `product__maximum_order_quantity` to access the `maximum_order_quantity` field of the related `Products` model.

However, the constraints attribute can only reference fields that belong to the same model. It cannot reference fields of related models.

Currently, you can override the `clean()` method as:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CartItems(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.quantity > self.product.maximum_order_quantity:
            raise ValidationError('Quantity cannot be more than maximum order quantity')
```

> **Note:** Models in Django don't require `s` to be added as suffix, since it is added by default. So it is better to change them as `CartItem` and `Product` from `CartItems` and `Products` respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'll try it out. And could you explain me why referrencing field on related models in db level constraints donot work. And does this clean() method check on database level?

Comment: @Sins97 Since models can be changed independently, and clean() method is used for validating.

Comment: Didn't understand it well. If could possible share me some resources regarding that and why referencing field on related models in db level constraints don't work.

Comment: @Sins97 Added more info, see edited answer.